# Adding record of page views and details of change to django_admin_log

Tags: django, django-admin

We are using LogEntry/django_admin_log and recording additions, changes and deletions made from Django Admin. However we have two issues we need to address:

1.) Changes record only the field that changed. Not the old and new values. We would like to add the specific details of all changes.

2.) We would like to record an action in this log every time a page is viewed on the Django Admin panel.

How would it be best to proceed?

We are happy to do some work to extend the existing functionality of this, or we are happy to move to a completely new 3rd part module if necessary, or write our own. But would like some guidance from some experts?

Answer (score 0):

We had similar requirements in terms of keeping history and track of actions done by users with a higher level of detail in terms of values changes. What we ended up doing was creating a new model called "History" which we populated with the user, the name of the model being changed, the instance id and a dictionary called changes showing the name of each field changed and values from - to.

In order to populate the new model, we overrode the save_model function in the admin file for the model we want to track. Regarding the page views, you can overrride the get_fields if "obj" is not None and create an instance of History accordingly.